# How to find a database row that matches a string?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a databse table with 100K rows and an array of 100 items. And I need to find if an array item is found in my Users table username row.

My database table Users

```
| id | username | fullname |
  1      John    John Smith
  2      Elliot  Jim Elliot
  3      Max     Max Richard
```

My array looks like this

```
[
   {
      string: 'Hello, this is Elliot from downtown Las Vegas!'
   },

   {
      string: 'Hey how are you?'
   }
]
```

My idea was to do a foreach loop through every row in my Users table (100k records) and find if it matches in my array, but it is so slow.

```
foreach ($MyArray as $Array) {
    foreach ($dbrows as $dbrow) {
        if (strpos($Array['string'], $dbrow['username']) !== false) {
            echo 'found it!';

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying "match" exactly? Are all first elements of the array the same (_Hello, this is Elliot..._)? Personally, I would be trying the extract the name (if that is what you are matching) from the array then do a database `in` search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be a bit hit and miss as you may find users with all sorts of weird names that match normal words, this approach splits the input into words and then uses them to form an `in` clause to search the database.  So it only looks at records that match rather than all records...

```
$search = 'Hello, this is Elliot from downtown Las a1 Vegas!';
$words = str_word_count($search, 1);
$bind  = str_repeat("?,", count($words));
$bind  = trim($bind, ",");

$query = $conn->prepare("select * from users where username in ($bind)" );
$types = str_repeat("s", count($words));
$query->bind_param($types, ...$words);
$query->execute();
$res = $query->get_result();
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())   {
    // Process result
}
```

It also uses prepared statements, which is where all of the `$bind` and `$types` processing comes in.  If you look at `$query` you will see how it's built up.

Comment: Is there also a solution for the cases where the string is without spaces like 'Hello my nameisElliot'?

Comment: There are always limits to any method, you could end up with users with partial matches to any word.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way was to separate your search arrays into words, and use it in the query, like:

```
<?php
// Assuming your search array is $search...
$words = array ();
foreach ( $search as $text)
{
  $words = array_merge ( $words, explode ( " ", trim ( preg_replace ( "/[^0-9a-z]+/i", " ", $text))));
}
$words = array_unique ( $words);
$in = "";
foreach ( $words as $text)
{
  $in .= ",'" . $mysqli->real_escape_string ( $text) . "'";
}
if ( ! $result = $mysqli->query ( "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `username` IN (" . substr ( $in, 1) . ")"))
{
  echo "MySQL error!";
}
// Results at $result
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
<?php

    $query_string = "bla bla bla...";

    $qry = $mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *FROM table WHERE username REGEXP '$query_string'");

?>
```

Regular expression matches data individually from table.